# im trying to use firebase to authenticate users but my app crshes when it loads the Intent method after successfully retreaving the credentials

Tags: java, android, firebase

String user_name=user.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
 String password=password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

```
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user_name,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        Toast.makeText(login.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Profile.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(login.this, "unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRyRc.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfEnN.jpg)
```

Comment: User fragment or activity context instead of getApplicationContext()

Comment: Check the error in the logcat, Profile might not be in the manifest. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: Welcome to SO! In addition to the other suggestions, you can also enable crash reporting via Firebase to receive detailed crash reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically everything is good in your code. maybe the Profile.class has some issue. debug on Profile.class

Comment: tnx there was a problem in the profile.java file